# Nuxt v2.10.2 auth middleware quest not work

Tags: nuxt-auth

For some reason middleware doesn't work for me, including  asyncData custom middlwhere

nuxt.config.js

```
    auth: {
        redirect: {
            login: '/auth/login',
            logout: false,
            callback: '/auth/login',
            home: false
        },
        strategies: {
            'laravelJWT': {
                provider: 'laravel/jwt',
                url: '/',
                endpoints: {
                    register: {url: '/auth/register', method: 'post', propertyName: false},
                    login: {url: '/auth/login', method: 'post', propertyName: false},
                    logout: {url: '/auth/logout', method: 'post', propertyName: false},
                    refresh: {url: '/auth/refresh', method: 'post', propertyName: false},
                    user: {url: '/auth/user', method: 'get', propertyName: false},
                },
                token: {
                    property: 'access_token',
                    maxAge: 60 * 60
                },
                refreshToken: {
                    maxAge: 20160 * 60
                },
            },
        },
        plugins: ['~/plugins/auth']
    },
```

login.vue copmonent

```
    export default {
        middleware: 'auth',
        auth : 'guest',
```

I tried also to create my middleware, but loggedIn only false(in asyncData too)

```
export default function ({ store, redirect, app }) {
    let locale = app.i18n.locale === app.i18n.defaultLocale ? '' : '/' + app.i18n.locale;
    console.log(app.$auth.loggedIn, store.state.auth.loggedIn,  app.$auth.$state.loggedIn, 'store.state.auth.loggedIn');
    if (store.state.auth.loggedIn) {
        return redirect( locale + '/' );
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not understand the problem, but I created a middleware